# How to map json response and create simple list with indexes

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, formatting

I am getting ingredients, preparings values from response and I want this text to be rendered with breaks, dashes and pointers when displayed on screen. How can I achievie this?

```
if let ingredients = dict["ingredients"] as? Array<String> {
                    self._ingredients = ingredients.joined(separator: " \n - ")
```

This works, however not for the first element in array.

```
4 elements
- 0 : "3 glasses of flour"
- 1 : "1 spoon of salt"
- 2 : "spices"
- 3 : "1 glass of hot water"
```

I want this to look on ViewController's label, like this:

```
 - 3 glasses of flour
 - 1 spoon of salt
 - spices
 - 1 glass of hot water
```

For preparing I want to add appropriate number pointer:

```
if let preparing = dict["preparing"] as? Array<String> {
                    self._preparing = preparing.joined(separator: "\n")
3 elements
 - 0 : "Mix dry ingredients."
 - 1 : "Add hot water, oil, sugar to yeast."
 - 2 : "When it's ready add this to flour and start combining"
```

So it looks like this in label:

```
1. Mix dry ingredients
2. Add hot water, oil and sugar to yeast
3. When it's ready add this to flour and start combining
```

**Additional info**
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3hUR.png) of how it look's currently (don't mind language, it's in polish).

And on this Controller's lifecycle I do simple updateUI

```
func updateUI () {
    pizzaDesc.text = pizza.description
    ingredientsDesc.text = pizza.ingredients
    PreparingDesc.text = pizza.preparings
    titleLbl.text = pizza.title
}

 //MARK: Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   hideTestDataOnLoad()
   pizza = PizzaRecipe()
   pizza.downloadRecipeDetails {
        self.updateUI()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of how it looks currently?  The current state is a bit ambiguous.  Can you also post the code for generating the full text you're assigning to the label?

Comment: @Frankie I have updated my question with additional info and image. I will try resolve this issue with answers already given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with this `dict`:

```
let jsonText = """
{
    "ingredients": [
        "3 glasses of flour",
        "1 spoon of salt",
        "spices",
        "1 glass of hot water"
    ],
    "preparing": [
        "Mix dry ingredients.",
        "Add hot water, oil, sugar to yeast.",
        "When it's ready add this to flour and start combining"
    ]
}
"""
let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonText.data(using:.utf8)!) as! [String: Any]
```

Case 1: `-` may not be a `separator`.

```
    if let ingredients = dict["ingredients"] as? Array<String> {
        self._ingredients = ingredients.map{" - \($0)"}.joined(separator: "\n")
        //...
    }
```

Case 2: You can get element index paired with each element using `enumerated()`.

```
    if let preparing = dict["preparing"] as? Array<String> {
        self._preparing = preparing.enumerated().map{"\($0+1). \($1)"}.joined(separator: "\n")
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So the reason this is confusing is that there are actually two different things you're trying to accomplish here:

1. You want to prefix each ingredient with a dash (- 3 eggs)
2. You want each item of the array on a different line

The problem you're running into is that `joined` only applies to BETWEEN items in an array, not to EACH item. You need to use `.map() {}` to do something to every item in an array (think of it like a for-loop).

So you'll achieve that like this:

```
let prefixed = ingredients.map() {"- " + $0}
let joined = prefixed.joined(separator: " \n")
label.text = joined
```